# Bijection between two sets of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, permutations

I'm studying discrete math and in my book the definition of permutation is as follows :

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set, it is called permutation of $X$ a bijective function $f: X \to X$.
>
> The set of all permutations is denoted by $S_X$.

which I get , then it is written

> To study $S_X$ where $|X| = n$ , it's enough to study $S_n$ (where $X = I_n = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$)

This is good to me because they have the same number of elements so it is intuitively true, but next there is the following proposition which should clarify the relation between $S_X$ and $S_n$ :

> Let $X$ be a finite set with $|X| = n$. Then there's a biejection $f : S_X \to S_n$ so that for all $\sigma , \pi \in S_X$ it is true that $f(\sigma \circ \pi ) = f(\sigma) \circ f(\pi) $. In particular  $|S_X |= n!$.

However I don't understand what does the part 'so that for all...$f(\sigma \circ \pi ) = f(\sigma) \circ f(\pi)$'. What's the intuitive and conceptual meaning for this formula?  can you help me to understand this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, $\circ$ denotes the composition of permutations, i.e. $\sigma \circ \pi$ is the permutation obtained by applying $\pi$, then applying $\sigma$. The statement says that there exists a "natural" bijection between $S_X$ and $S_n$, in the sense that it preserves the law of composition. If you have already heard about group morphisms, this just says that there exists a group isomorphism between $(S_X, \circ)$ and $(S_n, \circ)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my problem is more with the second part $f(\sigma) \circ f(\pi)$ , in this case it means $f(f(\pi))$?

Comment: @Tortar This is the same ! $f(\sigma)$ and $f(\pi)$ are elements of $S_n$, therefore you can compose them : $f(\sigma) \circ f(\pi)$ is the permutation obtained by composing the permutation $f(\sigma)$ with the permutation $f(\pi)$... This is not the same thing as $f(f(\pi))$ which has no sense : indeed $f(\pi)$ belongs to $S_n$ and not to $S_X$, so you cannot talk about $f(f(\pi))$.

Comment: ah right, I'm a beginner in this things about functions, it's not so intuitive for me! :p,

Comment: @Tortar A good first approach is to always verify that what you write has sense, just checking that you apply functions to elements which belong to the domain of the function. You will avoid lots of mistakes, just checking that !

Comment: thanks for the tip, can you please clarify a bit better what you it's meant by preserving the law of composition? Because I have never heard about group morphisms

Comment: @Tortar Very frequently, when you consider sets which have a specific structure (which means that there are "laws" on them), the natural way to define "good" maps on these sets is to ask for a certain compatibility between the maps and the law. For example, on vector spaces (if you know what it is), we consider linear maps, which are the maps that "behave well" w.r.t. the laws of vector space (sum and external multiplication). This is the same here : $S_X$ and $S_n$ are what we call groups, for the law $\circ$, and "good" maps on them are maps such that $f(x \circ y)=f(x) \circ f(y)$.

Comment: But you will understand this far better when you will hear about groups and group morphisms, so don't worry if this is not clear at the moment.